# Firebase and UISearchbarController searching via the server and not the client -Swift iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchcontroller

Does anyone have any info on how to incorporate Firebase into a UISearchController delegate? I can't find any solid info on it. There may possibly be thousands of employees.

I know how to use the search controller delegates `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` and using a `NSPredicate` to filter what I'm looking for if I was using NSUserDefaults but using Firebase I'm uncertain.

I've added some more code to my question

I have a custom data model object saved in FirebaseDatabase and I'd like to search on all of the following properties within the object.

```
lastName
idNumber
deptNumber
position
```

Searching any of these properties should first show a partial string inside the table cells until the entire string i'm looking for is shown. So if I typed in the letter "S" then all employee last names beginning with "S" should show. If I enter "Sa" the in would filter to those letters". From my understanding I should use "\u{f8ff}" to get the partial search string but no data is returned.

Anyhow here's all the code

My object is:

```
class Employee{
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?
var idNumber: String?
var deptNumber: String?
var position: String?
}
```

My paths

```
-root
  -users
    -uid
      |_"email":"emailAddress"
      |_"userID":"uid"
      |_"firstName":"firstName"
      |_"lastName":"lastName"
  -employees
    -hireDate
      -uid //this is the same uid from the users node so I know who's who
        |_"firstName":"firstName"
        |_"lastName":"lastName"
        |_"idNum":"idNumber"
        |_"deptNumber":"deptNumber"
        |_"position":"position"
```

My rules:

What's happening here is the day an employee is hired they are asked to create a company account using their email address and pw.
At the same time a "employees" path is created with a child being a "hireDate" path and finally the employees "uid" path. This employee "uid" is the path I want to search on from the "employees" node

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users" : {
          "$uid" : {
              ".read": true,
              ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
          }
      },
      "employees": {
          "$hireDate": {
              "$uid": {
                 ".read": true,
                 ".indexOn": ["lastName", "idNumber", "deptNumber", "position"]
              }
          }
     }
  }
}
```

My searchController

```
import UIKit

class SearchController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var searchController: UISearchController!
var employeesToFilter = [Employee]()
var filteredSearchResults = [Employee]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    //all searchController properties get set here no need to include them though

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let employeeRef = ref.child("employees")

    employeeRef?.queryOrderedByChild("lastName").queryStartingAtValue("\u{f8ff}").queryLimitedToFirst(20).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {

        (snapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            let firstName = dict["firstName"] as! String
            let lastName = dict["lastName"] as! String
            let idNumber = dict["idNumber"] as! String
            let deptNumber = dict["deptNumber"] as! String
            let position = dict["position"] as! String

            let employee = Employee()
            employee.firstName = firstName
            employee.lastName = lastName
            employee.idNumber = idNumber
            employee.deptNumber = deptNumber
            employee.position = position

            self.employeesToFilter.append(employee)
        }
    })
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.searchController.active = true
}

deinit {
    self.searchController = nil
}

}


//MARK:- TableView Datasource
extension SearchBuildingController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.filteredSearchResults.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchCell

    let searchString = self.filteredSearchResults[indexPath.row]

    cell.firstNameLabel.text = searchString.firstName
    cell.lastNameLabel.text = searchString.lastName
    cell.idNumberLabel.text = searchString.idNumber
    cell.deptNumberLabel.text = searchString.deptNumber
    cell.positionLabel.text = searchString.position
    return cell
}
}

//MARK:- SearchController Delegates
extension SearchController: UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate{

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.employeesToFilter.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    self.filteredSearchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: SELF.lastName CONTAINS [c] %@ OR SELF.idNumber CONTAINS [c] %@ OR SELF.deptNumber CONTAINS[c] %@ OR SELF.position CONTAINS [c] %@", searchText!, searchText!, searchText!, searchText!)

    let array = (self.employeesToFilter as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredSearchResults = array as! [Employee]

    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: You don't search solely for `"\u{f8ff}"`; that doesn't make any sense since you haven't given it the "starts with" criteria. So instead you want something like `startingAtValue("S")` and `endingAtValue("S\u{f8ff}");`. Note that trying to implement advanced fuzzy/contextual search in Firebase is generally more complexity than it's worth. A proper search engine would be much more robust and, in my opinion, far less complex to get up and running. See [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) for an example of how to integrate search with Firebase.

Comment: @Kato Thanks I'm looking into it

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I have accomplished this using Firebase building a list of campuses. This method loads all of the data that is in the table view up front making it easy to search and filter.

My campus object is pretty simple with an id and a name.

```
struct Campus {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}
```

In the view controller I have two arrays. One is to hold the list of all campuses returned and the other array is for the filtered campuses.

```
let campuses = [Campus]()
let filteredCampuses = [Campus]()
```

I then called a method that I had set up to load the campuses from Firebase.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    getAllCampusesFromFirebase() { (campuses) in
        self.campuses = campuses
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Then when performing the search I filter out the campuses comparing the campus name to the search text from the search bar.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else {
        return
    }

    filteredCampuses = campuses.filter { campus in
        return campus.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you are not loading all of the data up front then Firebase provides some handy methods to call that you can use to filter the data based on the reference path. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

`queryStarting(atValue)` or `queryStarting(atValue:childKey:)` would probably be the one that you'd want to use in this case.

```
ref.queryStarting(atValue: Any?)
ref.queryStarting(atValue: Any?, childKey: String?)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was working on search earlier today. I think loading all the FB data into the array would cause a serious performance issue if you had billions of campus objects inside the db. To query directly from the db via queryStart.. seems to be the way the go if massive data is there. I'm lost at 2 places though. 1. How do you get the queryData into the campus array or the filtered array? 2. How do you query on multiple properties for e.g. How would you query on both campus id and name? Also if you had a location property how would you include that? Those are 3 diff values to query on.

Comment: 1) To get the queryData you would perform an `observe(FIRDataEventType:with)` method on the path that you are searching such `ref.queryStarting(atValue).observeEvent(FIRDataEventType:with)`. This will return the data for your query and then just populate the filtered array with that data. 2) To get multiple queries you can chain together your queries `ref.queryStarting(atValue).queryStarting(atValue)` etc. Though I have not tried this yet so not sure if it treats the queries as AND or OR when it has multiple values. 3) For location searches I have used GeoFire before & it works pretty well.

Comment: I updated my answer with more code. When you get a chance please let me know what you think.

Comment: @LanceSamaria sorry just responding. Have been traveling. The suggestion that Kato made was going to be my suggestion as well with the startingAtValue and endingAtValue. Hope that that helps and gets you what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help. ElastiSearch/Flaslight seems to be the way to go. I believe that's all prebuilt in. Getting it to work is my new query :)